# Using Fetch API to get flicker feed in json format

Tags: javascript, json, cors, fetch-api, flicker

I manage to get json response from flicker feed api by using $.getJSON, but when i try to do it using Fetch i only seems to get an XML response.

This works:

```
var flickerAPI = "http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?";
$.getJSON(flickerAPI, {
                    tags: "searchTerm",
                    tagmode: "any",
                    format: "json"
                })
                .done(function (data) {
                   //....
                });
```

This does not work:

```
var flickerAPI = "http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?";

var request = new Request(flickerAPI, { 
                mode: 'no-cors',
                tags: 'searchTerm',
                tagmode: 'any',
                format: 'json'
            });

            fetch(request)
                .then(function (res) {
                    return res.json();
                })
                .then(function (text) {
                    console.log(text);
                });
```

I also would like to understand why when using the Fetch API i am getting:
"No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled." and when using  $.getJSON not.
Thank you !!

Comment: i've never used the API nor fetch, but as per the docs https://www.flickr.com/services/feeds/docs/photos_public/ (tags, tagmode, format, ...) are query parameters, which means they have to be in the URL itself, `photos_public.gne?format=json&tagmode=any&jsoncallback=...` ??

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do this with fetch(), I'm trying the same thing now and getting the same error.  Hoping not to have to switch to jsonp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: the args for the `fetch(…)` method and behavior of the `fetch(…)` method are very different from the args for the `$.getJSON(…)` method and the behavior of the `$.getJSON(…)` method—so you can’t expect `fetch(…)` to do anything like what `$.getJSON(…)` does.

Longer answer, responding to your specific questions:

> I also would like to understand why when using the Fetch API i am
>   getting: "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the
>   requested resource… and when using $.getJSON not.

Your request URL contains the substring `callback=?`, so [`$.getJSON` handles it as JSONP](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/#jsonp):

> If the URL includes the string "callback=?" (or similar, as defined by the server-side API), the request is treated as JSONP instead.

…which means that behind the scenes, instead of sending a cross-origin request from JavaScript, it instead creates a `script` element that loads the JSONP response. Since browsers allow the `script` element to be used to load scripts cross-origin, that never runs into any restrictions.

But when you make the call using the Fetch API, that doesn’t do any behind-the-scenes magic to automatically recognize the request as a JSONP request based on the URL, and doesn’t create a `script` element to load the response. Instead it just causes a request to get made directly to that `http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?"` URL.

But `http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?"` isn’t actually intended to be used with the Fetch API or XHR, so the response it sends back doesn’t include the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header.

Per the CORS protocol, to a browser the lack of that `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header means *“Don’t expose this response to any client-side JavaScript running in a web app”*.

So your browser logs that *“No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access”* message to let you know your script won’t be able to access the response, and why.

If you’re setting `mode: 'no-cors'` I wouldn’t expect you’d be seeing that message. But you basically never want to set `mode: 'no-cors'` anyway, because doing so has the same effect as the lack of the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header does—it prevents your script from having any access to the response at all.

---

As far as expecting `tags: 'searchTerm'`, `tagmode: 'any'`, and `format: 'json'` to have any effect if you specify them in the object you give as the second argument to the `fetch(…)` method, @Yazan’s comment above is right: those are custom query params for the flickr API, so if you’re doing a GET request with the Fetch API you need to specify them in the URL as query params.

`$.getJSON`, in contrast, [does that for you automatically](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/):

> Data that is sent to the server is appended to the URL as a query string.

…where the data it means is the object of name/value pairs you give as the 2nd arg to `$.getJSON`.

In contrast, for the `fetch(…)` method, the names and values you specify in the second argument can’t be arbitrary query parameters. Instead only [a predefined set of names are allowed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch#Parameters) there:

- `method`: The request method, e.g., GET, POST.
- `headers`: Any headers you want to add to your request
- `body`: Any body that you want to add to your request
- `mode`: The mode you want to use for the request
- `credentials`: The request credentials you want to use for the request
- `cache`: The cache mode you want to use for the request
- `redirect`: The redirect mode to use
- `referrer`: A USVString specifying no-referrer, client, or a URL
- `referrerPolicy`: Specifies the value of the referer HTTP header
- `integrity`: Contains the subresource integrity value of the request